# How to save changes/add new objects to related entities Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, relational-database, primary-key

I have two tables that are related in SQL:

```
 MasterPartNumbers           MasterPartsLists
 (pk) pn       (one-> many)  (fk) pn
      desc                        parentAssemblyPn
                             (pk) partsListLineItemID
```

Note: `MasterPartNumbers` does share a navigational relationship to `MasterPartsList`, but the "many" side of the relationship (`MasterPartsLists.pn`) is not a primary or unique key. The same `pn` (part number) can belong to several different `parentAssmeblyPn`s

Now, I want to make sure that any data that is added to my `ObjectContext` that belongs to either of these two entities is relayed to the other.

Question 1: how do I use the .Include() method to relay relevant information when adding new objects to the context (_context.MasterPartNumbers.AddObject(someEnumerable)) and applying .SaveChanges()?

Comment: " I was unable to access properties from my Include-ed table, which was strange to me" What does that mean? Why?

Comment: I actually just noticed that EF added the primary key to the foreign key column. This however is incorrect because the same `pn` could be linked to many different assemblies (`parentAssyPn`s).

Comment: @usr -- I pretty significantly updated my question.